# joomla 3.0 pass variable from index to view

Tags: joomla3.0

I am trying to pass a variable from the index page to an article view. Basically the width of a div needs to change based on whether there are sidebars.

index.php:

```
if ($this->countModules('position-1')&$this->countModules('position-3')){
    $content_margin = 'contentCenter';
}elseif ($this->countModules('position-1')&!$this->countModules('position-3')){
    $content_margin = 'contentRight';
}elseif (!$this->countModules('position-1')&$this->countModules('position-3')){
    $content_margin = 'contentLeft';
}else{
    $content_margin = '';
}
```

How do I then access the $content_margin variable within the component?

```
<jdoc:include type="component" class="<?php echo $content_margin; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather try something like this:

```
<div class="<?php echo $content_margin; ?>">
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>
```

You do not need to pass this variable into your component, just give your CSS classes different widths.

If you want to count the number of modules in your component you could look at [this](http://www.corephp.com/blog/how-to-use-countmodules-in-any-joomla-file/#.UXl677UerIU) link

Comment: I did that in the end however it required the use of border-box; `#contentContain { 
    float:left;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; *behavior: url(/boxsizing.htc); 
}`